# Expressing sum of money in terms of changes

Tags: haskell

I have been studying Haskell for a week and trying to write some real world functions by myself. My aim is expressing sum of money in terms of respective coins and amount of said coins. But I am not sure if I am thinking "functionally" when i write functions. Example code is below;

```
changes = [1,2,5,10,25,50]

makechanges n cs = if n `div` (last cs) > 0
                     then (coin_amount, last cs) : makechanges (n - coin_amount * current_coin ) (init cs)
                     else makechanges n (init cs)
                   where coin_amount = n `div` (last cs)
                         current_coin = last cs
```

Example output is

```
makechanges 126 changes
[(50,2),(25,1),(1,1)]
```

Is there a more FP way to write intended function? I feel like this function is just conversion of imperative function, thanks in advance.

Comment: An obvious improvement would be to reverse the `changes` list. Lists are asymmetric, `last` and `init` are expensive, `head` and `tail` are cheap.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I totally forgot linked list structure of haskell lists.

Comment: My style suggestion is to forget the partial functions `head,tail` as well, and simply stick to pattern matching. I also second the n.m. suggestion of reversing the list: start with the larger coin.

Answer (score 1):

A left fold solution would be:

```
change :: (Foldable t, Integral a) => a -> t a -> [(a, a)]
change total coin = foldl go (const []) coin total
    where
    go run c x = if x < c then run x else (c, x `div` c): run (x `mod` c)
```

then:

```
\> change 126 [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50]
[(50,2),(25,1),(1,1)]
```

Comment: As I have been working for a week(not in full day-night time) , Foldable, go and run does not ring a bell for now. But surely I will continue to study and revisit this solution.